# Why would Chrome take 12 seconds to do an Update Layer Tree?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, timeline

I have a relatively un-complex ASP.Net application, which occasionally displays an alert message in layer, with a shadow, with a pushbutton to dismiss the notification.

This code has been working fine for years.

Lately, I am getting complaints from users of really slow response.  What they experience is that the page is completely unresponsive, and when they click on the [OK] pushbutton nothing happens for a really long time.

When I record a Timeline, I can see the original even which caused a round-trip to the webserver, and I can see the response from the webserver.  I can also see all the Javascript code which runs as a result of the response.

As far as the application is concerned, the transaction is over, and, as far as the Javascript is concerned, the transaction is over as well.  All we need to do is wait for the user to click the [OK] button and we will dismiss the notification popup.

This is where the "freeze" happens.  The [OK] event is not delivered for like 20-30 seconds.  What's going on in the meantime?  That's why I'm writing:

We see some very short timers fire every once in a while, then we see a quick Recalculate Style call, followed by an Update Layer Tree event.

The Update Layer Tree event takes 10-12 seconds!

[image: The Update Layer Tree event takes 10-12 seconds (not milliseconds)]

Here's the code for the dialog which is going unresponsive because of the Update Layer Tree events  The  gets displayed first as you see it here, then, if something goes wrong, it may get updated with code similar to showAlert:

[Status/error dialog code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr6gm.png)

Comment: You'll probably need to post some code to get the help you need

Comment: I will post some code tomorrow ... but in the meantime, can anyone think of any possible reason Chrome should go into such a state?  12 seconds to do an Update Layer Tree? ... and as you can see in the plot, it does it again a few seconds later!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25724126/chrome-devtools-timeline-update-layer-tree-event

Comment: TIblu ... I read that article, that mentions many calls to Update Layer Tree ... My case has a single call to Update Layer Tree which takes 10 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See @tiblu's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640343/why-would-chrome-take-12-seconds-to-do-an-update-layer-tree/33763072?noredirect=1#comment55066911_33640343) for detail on *why* Chrome would perform `Update Layer Tree`.

As for taking 12 seconds: does the interaction behave normally in other browsers, for example Firefox or Safari? If your code has been working fine for years as you say and the browser response issues have been popping up recently (> mid-October, 2015) and only in Chrome the issue *may* not be your code.

There are a number of similar new issues and complaints recently, pointing to the release of Chrome 46. For example: [this issue (code.google.com)](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=545441) and [this issue (code.google.com)](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=544222&q=cpu&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).

CPU spikes are responsible for browser unresponsiveness, which you can monitor using Chrome's Task Manager. As for *why* CPU is spiking and further detail you'll need to follow the issues above and others as they develop.

*Apologies for the pseudo-answer, don't currently have the rep to slip this into a comment.*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10237048)

Comment: Thanks *markus* and especially @YanFoto for grokking my situation and providing the tip on gaining rep. I can pull this answer if needed but would prefer to keep the above information in context and publicly available if possible.

Comment: The issue did start within the past month or so, and it does only happen in Chrome, and everyone is running version 46.  Very interesting.

Comment: @TLMAGE please accept my answer if you feel I've addressed your issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all who responded ... I was unable to figure out how to re-install an older version of Chrome, but I did manage to get my hands on a beta version of Chrome 48 (48.0.2564.8), and, to my most pleasant surprise, I am no longer able to reproduce the problem.

Just to be sure, I restored 46 from this morning's BACKUP, and it re-exhibited the issue.  After re-installing beta-48, the problem is gone.

Hooray!  Well done everyone!