# Switching between inputs is slow in a large HTML table

Tags: html, performance, html-table, rendering

I have created a wholesale order form in the form of a large HTML table with lots of number inputs. I've noticed that switching between number inputs and typing values in the inputs are very slow in this table (ie. when I click in an input, it takes time for the cursor to show up; when I type in an input, it takes time for the character to show up). Is there any way for me to remove the lag without paginating the table rows?

You can view and play around with the table [here](https://harlequin-nature-graphics.myshopify.com/collections/wholesale) (use guest password "braese").

A screenshot of a Chrome Dev Tools performance recording for clicking inside a single input (I'm not really sure what to make of this):
[image: Chrome Dev Tools performance recording]

Comment: where is your "wholesale order form"?

Comment: I got to the "wholesale order form". Can you describe the specific input sequence that caused the "very slow" processing? Also, does your performance concern pertain to browser processing with JavaScript, or something else?

Comment: checkout my answer below. works like a charm .

Comment: @JohnH It has nothing to do with JavaScript. When you click inside any of the number inputs, there is a lag before the cursor starts blinking. Then when you type something, there is a lag before each character shows up in the input box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some more digging and testing, and it turns out the lag (update layer tree) when clicking/typing in inputs is only an issue in Chrome. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33763072/1032766) on another question points to issues with Chrome since version 46. It's a shame that such a popular browser has allowed an issue like this to go on for 2+ years. We will have to paginate our order form since Chrome is so popular with our client's customers.

Answer (score 0):

Wow my chrome almost crashed :) 
It is your styles
You are causing layer creation every time you apply translate transform
Check out the Layers menu in Chrome Dev tools;
Test if it runs better - only table :)

Also order your styles and scripts! - first styles after that scripts

Cheers!

Comment: "You are causing layer creation every time you apply translate transform" - where am I applying translate transform? It is not applied to the inputs. The problem is, when I click in one of the inputs, there is a lag before the cursor shows up, and when I type something in an input there is a lag before the character shows up.

"Test if it runs better - only table" - you mean test it after removing translate transform? What do you mean by "only table"?

"first styles after that scripts" - my scripts should be loading just before </body>... what did you see that makes you think otherwise?

Comment: </div>
  
  <!-- CUSTOM JAVASCRIPT -->
  
  
   <script defer src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2143/7693/t/2/assets/wholesale-form.js?6937108773544854703"></script>
  
  
  
  
  
  <!-- LOAD CUSTOM CSS STYLES -->
  
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2143/7693/t/2/assets/page.wholesale-form.scss?6937108773544854703" />

</body>

Comment: also table only means 
Try this 
open the slow page
Open Developer Tools ->Network-> F5 to refresh
Spot your theme.scss

https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2143/7693/t/2/assets/theme.scss.css?...
Right click -> Block request URL 
F5 to refresh again 
now you see the page with the HUGE table -> Notice the input fields 
No lag! 

Cheers

Comment: You're right, blocking theme.scss.css does speed up the form a whole lot. The question is, which CSS rule(s) were causing "Update Layer Tree" to take sooooo long? (see my Dev Tools screenshot above)

Comment: Do i have to do all for you ?
.page-container {
    -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

Comment: There's no need to be rude. I'm asking my question on StackOverflow because I don't know what's causing the problem. I don't know how you arrived at that conclusion, but disabling those CSS rules doesn't make the form run any faster for me.

Comment: not being rude sorry if it sounded that way - did it work?

Comment: No worries. No, like I said, disabling those CSS rules doesn't make the form run any faster for me. Thanks for trying though. :) I found the answer I think - see the accepted answer.