# Render Loop: Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

A browser may go through several steps in rendering a frame, such as:

1. CSS Recalculation - the browser creates/updates the DOM and CSSOM accordingly and creates  render tree
2. Layout - figures out where and how the elements are positioned on the screen
3. Update Layer Tree
4. Paint - draws the pixels. It divides the entire page into layers so as to minimise the paint area on updates
5. Composite Layers - composites the various layers together into the final screen image
6. Rasterize Paint

In #3 above, what is a "Layer Tree"?

Comment: See [Render-tree construction, layout, and paint](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction?hl=en)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome DevTools Timeline Update Layer Tree Event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25724126/chrome-devtools-timeline-update-layer-tree-event)

Comment: I can't see  where "Layer Tree" is explained. I can just find "Update Layer Tree" and "Render Layer". Thank you for the links

Comment: See also: [The Rendering Critical Path](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/the-rendering-critical-path) (follow the doc links too) and [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/frame/FrameView.cpp?q=UpdateLayerTree+-file:test&sq=package:chromium&l=2652&dr=C)

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm