# What leverage can be used to reduce UpdateLayerTree operation in Blink?

Tags: javascript, css, chromium, blink

I'm working on web application embedded in low-end devices and i'm experiencing long `update layer tree` operations while rendering.

I know that `update layer tree` is the operation which consist in computing or recomputing the information relatives to `RenderLayers`, usually because a top layer has been invalidated. I found this previous post which explain this pretty well : [Chrome DevTools Timeline Update Layer Tree Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25724126/chrome-devtools-timeline-update-layer-tree-event).

My application is built around components and each one of them might have a few layers. If i test my components separately, everything works fine and i get great performances (great fps, smooth animations). Now, when i put everything together, the performances are falling apart. What i'm seeing in chrome dev tools are long `UpdateLayerTree`.

I was wondering what is the leverage to address this ?
I guess the first obvious action is to try to reduce the amount of layers within the whole application. But here are my questions :

- Are the amount of layer the only leverage to reduce UpdateLayerTree ? (For example, does the size of a layer has any impact on this ?)
- Are there some tricks which triggers a quick rendering path in Blink which can avoid or reduce update layer tree operations in some particular cases (i think this is the case for inline transform ?)
- Do you see something else ?

Regards,

(Also, as a side note, i opened an issue in chromium project to get some feedback around this some time ago : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=725712.)

Answer (score 0):

So running into a few tests, it looks like that `UpddateLayerTree` is mostly impacted by the amount of layers and not really about the size of each layer. Thinking about this, it actually makes sense because the `UpdateLayerTree` operation is about recomputing information of each layers.

Just as an information in case it helps someone else, regarding my personal case and this previous information, i'm addressing those long UpdateLayerTree operations with the following actions :

1. Reduce the amount of layers (usually by removing positionned elements) when its possible
2. Use `display:none` when an element is not actually visible in the viewport. `display:none` as a double benefit : elements are already parsed  but they are not rendered. As they are not rendered, they are ignored by `UpdateLayerTree` operation but it still makes it fast to render if we need to (since they are already in the DOM).

Maybe, some of you will come up with other techniques ?