# Meaning of long frame in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to figure out why my application performs very bad. So I did a performance record within DevTools and I can see that frames usually takes about 150 ms which is too long.

[image]
[image]

However I don't understand why the frame takes so much time. There is some javascript handling an input event, some DOM manipulation and some paint. It all takes about 60 ms. So why is the frame 150 ms long?

**EDIT**
I've enabled some timeline-related devtools experiments as wOxxOm suggested. There is some kind of Update Layer task.

[image]

Comment: Scroll the flamechart all the way down - maybe your GPU is congested. Or something else. Also try enabling some timeline-related devtools experiments: https://puu.sh/AHxnb/242921211d.png

Comment: See the updated question. I don't have such a setting in my DevTools. I have switched Developer Tools Experiments on, but I've got much less options available than you.

Comment: Press `Shift` 6 or 7 times when on the Experiments pane. Ignore any OS prompts if you're in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I would have said it came from too much nodes in your layer, but with some research we can now find that [someone already had your problem before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25724126/chrome-devtools-timeline-update-layer-tree-event). To quote the answerer :

> In your case, I would guess that you are triggering a fundamental
>   layer invalidation that is forcing it to update a layer high up on the
>   tree hierarchy which is then trickling down the tree and causing each
>   of those layers to be updated. Although its hard to say without
>   looking at your code.
>
> Either way if this long Update Layer Tree is consistently happening
>   before the Layout is being recalculated, it's most certainly related
>   to that.

I'll advise checking the ressource pointed by Alexander J. Ray, especially the [HTML5 Rocks article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/).

Comment: Well, that's something I would like to understand. In the question you mention, there is 'Update Layer Tree' event. It's purple which IMHO means its related to the layout part. In my case it's called 'Update Layer' and it's green - so its about painting. I can't find anything about such event on the Internet. There is no Timeline panel in the Chrome DevTools anymore too.

Comment: The question is 4 years old, so I wouldn' be surprised if colors and mentions changed since. But there is indeed a possibility that "Update Layer" and "Update Layer Tree" are unrelated, and if so I'm out of ideas ^^